# Forcing C++ error on unwanted macro use

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a macro used everywhere

```
   #define DBG(s) do_something_with(s)
```

However, in one of the files, I want to make it impossible to use - and cause a compile error

```
#ifdef DBG
#undef DBG
#define DBG(s) #error "do not use DBG in this file"
#endif
```

Obviously, my example does not work. Any suggestions how something like this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, you may do something like:

```
#ifdef DBG
# undef DBG
#endif
#define DBG(s) static_assert(false, "you should not use this macro")
```

With error message like:

```
C:/Code/Test/src/src/main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
C:/Code/Test/src/src/main.cpp:38:16: error: static assertion failed: you should not use this macro
 #define DBG(s) static_assert(false, "you should not use this macro")
                ^
C:/Code/Test/src/src/main.cpp:45:5: note: in expansion of macro 'DBG'
     DBG(42);
     ^
```

In C/C++03, a simple `#undef` will result to something like:

```
C:/Code/Test/src/src/main.cpp:45:11: error: 'DBG' was not declared in this scope
```

which may be enough.

Comment: Similar holds for C11 (since the question is also tagged C)

Comment: In C11 it is `_Static_assert`, also available at least in GCC and Clang as an extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to avoid DBG usage by the preprocessor, the most pre-processors support the `#error` directive which you can use,

```
#ifdef DBG
#error "do not use DBG in this file"
#endif
```

However if you want to prevent the macro from being expanded in the code, you can rely on the `sizeof` of an undefined type `DBG` to fail at compile time,

```
#ifdef DBG
#undef DBG
#define DBG sizeof("Don't use the " + DBG +" macro in this file")
#endif
```

Comment: This may be confusing "use the macro" and "define the macro" - the macro is probably defined in a header somewhere.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks, I think I've clarified this now.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it to do something invalid, of course.

Then you'll get compilation errors, but they won't be very "clear".

Something like:

```
#undef DBG
#define DBG(s) please_dont_use_dbg_in_this_file()
```

Or as pointed out in a comment, just leave it undefined, then you'll get an error about an undefined reference:

```
#undef DBG
```

That can perhaps be considered clearer, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You could just remove the second line (un-define `DBG` and don't re-define it), which would cause (correct, IMO) error messages about an undeclared identifier `DBG` if used anyway.

Comment: The idea is ok but the function will not do it: void fn() { DBG(x); // function declaration }

Comment: @DieterLücking True ... that assumes implicit `int` though, you should have a warning preventing that. :) Still, I guess it's an argument for providing a bogus definition.

Comment: @unwind what about: `typedef please_dont_use_dbg_in_this_file please_dont_use_dbg_in_this_file`

Answer (score 1):

Just do this in your .cpp file

```
#ifdef DBG
#undef DBG
#endif
```

This way your compilation will fail upon encountering DBG